# Function of two variables, derivation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

If $t = \frac{1}{2}((y_{1})^{2} + (y_{2})^{2})$ and if it written that $u$ and $v$ are functions depending on $t$, does that mean that $(y_{1})^{2}$ and $(y_{2})^{2}$ must be "parts " of $u$, i. e. we can choose, for example that $u=e^{(y_{1})^{2} + (y_{2})^{2}}$ and not $u=e^{(y_{1})^{2}}$.

Then, if we choose $u=e^{(y_{1})^{2} + (y_{2})^{2}}$, and we have $v=\frac{-uu'}{2tu'-u}$,how to calculate $u'$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would definitely mean that $(y_1)^2 + (y_2)^2 \in u$. Think of it this way. If A is member of B, and B is a member of C, then it follows that A is also is a member of C. I would also like to add that any linear combination of $y_1 and y_2$ within the domain of t would also be members of u. And to calculate u' I believe this would just be the gradient of u in two dimensions. One dimension being $y_1$ and the other being $y_2$. So u'=$\nabla u$= $\partial u\over \partial y_1 $ + $\partial u \over \partial y_2$. I'll leave the plugging in to you. Hope this helps.